# Possible to do this more efficiently (turn compact file to sparse)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read in a file line by line that has indices of where a vector has 1's

so for example:
1 3 9 10

means:
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1

My goal is to write program that will take each line and print out the full vector with the 0's.

I am able to do this with my current program for a few lines:

```
#create a sparse vector
list_line_sparse = [0] * int(num_features)

#loop over all the lines
for item in lines:
    #split the line on spaces
    zz = item.split(' ')
    #get all ints on a line
    d = [int(x.strip()) for x in zz]
    #loop over all ints and change index to 1 in sparse vector
    for i in d:
        list_line_sparse[i]=1

    out_file += (', '.join(str(item) for item in list_line_sparse))
    #change back to 0's
    for i in d:
        list_line_sparse[i]=0
    out_file +='\n'


f = open('outfile', 'w')
f.write(out_file)
f.close()
```

The problem is that for a file with a lot of features and lines, my program is very very inefficient - it basically never finishes. Is there anything sticking out that I should change to make it more efficent? (I.e. the 2 for loops)

Comment: For what value of num features the program is slow? Can you give a sample test case?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more efficient to write each line of data to your output file as it is generated, rather than building up a huge string in memory.

`numpy` is a popular Python module that's good for doing bulk operations on numbers.  If you start with:

```
import numpy as np
list_line_sparse = np.zeros(num_features, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then, given `d` as the list of numbers on the current line, you can simply do:

```
list_line_sparse[d] = 1
```

to set ALL of those indexes in the array at the same time, no loop required.  (At the Python level at least, obviously there's still a loop involved, but it's down in the C implementation of numpy).

Answer (score 0):

It is slowing down because you are doing string concatenation. It is better to work with lists.

Also you could use `csv` to read your space separated lines in, and to then write each row with commas automatically added:

```
import csv

num_features = 20

with open('input.txt', 'r', newline='') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_output:    
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        list_line_sparse = [0] * int(num_features)

        for v in map(int, row):
            list_line_sparse[v] = 1

        csv_output.writerow(list_line_sparse)
```

So if `input.txt` contained the following:

```
1 3 9 10
1 3 9 11
2 7 3 5
```

Giving you an `output.txt` containing:

```
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Too much loops: first, the `item.split()`, then the `for x in zz`, then `for i in d`, then `for item in list_line_sparse`, and then `for i in d` again. Strings concatenations could be your most expensive part: the `.join` and the `output +=`. And all this for every line.

You could try a "character by character" parsing and writing. Something like this:

```
#features per line
count = int(num_features)
f = open('outfile.txt', 'w')

#loop over all lines
for item in lines:
    #reset the feature
    i = 0
    #the characters buffer
    index = ""

    #parse character by character
    for character in item:
        #if a space or end of line is found,
        #and the characters buffer (index) is not empty
        if character in (" ", "\r", "\n"):
            if index:
                #parse the characters buffer
                index = int(index)
                #if is not the first feature
                if i > 0:
                    #add the separator
                    f.write(", ")
                #add 0's until index
                while i < index:
                    f.write("0, ")
                    i += 1
                #and write 1
                f.write("1")
                i += 1
                #reset the characters buffer
                index = ""
        #if is not a space or end on line
        else:
            #add the character to the buffer
            index += character

    #if the last line didn't end with a carriage return,
    #index could be waiting to be parsed
    if index:
        index = int(index)
        if i > 0:
            f.write(", ")
        while i < index:
            f.write("0, ")
            i += 1
        f.write("1")
        i += 1
        index = ""

    #fill with 0's
    while i < count:
        if i == 0:
            f.write("0")
        else:
            f.write(", 0")
        i += 1

    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's rework your code into a simpler package that takes better advantage of Python's features:

```
import sys

NUM_FEATURES = 12

with open(sys.argv[1]) as source, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as sink:
    for line in source:
        list_line_sparse = [0] * NUM_FEATURES

        indicies = map(int, line.rstrip().split())

        for index in indicies:
            list_line_sparse[index] = 1

        print(*list_line_sparse, file=sink, sep=',')
```

I revisited this problem with your *"more efficiently"* in mind.  Although the above is more memory efficient, it is a hair slower time-wise.  I reconsidered your original and came up with a solution that is less memory efficient but about 2x faster than your code:

```
import sys

NUM_FEATURES = 12

data = ''

with open(sys.argv[1]) as source:
    for line in source:
        list_line_sparse = ["0"] * NUM_FEATURES

        indicies = map(int, line.rstrip().split())

        for index in indicies:
            list_line_sparse[index] = "1"

        data += ",".join(list_line_sparse) + '\n'

with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as sink:
    sink.write(data)
```

Like your original solution, it stores all the data in memory and writes it out at the end which is both a disadvantage (memory-wise) and an advantage (time-wise.)

**input.txt**

```
1 3 9 10
1 3 9 11
2 7 3 5
```

**USAGE**

```
% python3 test.py input.txt output.txt
```

**output.txt**

```
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
```